# iPad screen doesn't support autolayout

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout

I have created view using autolayout it works fine in all iPhone devices but it left some blank space at left, right, top and bottom on iPad.
I tried to make another xib specially for iPad which is 768*1024 but still facing same problem.
here is the screenshot of iPad output.[image: Black portion is not expected]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to **make this a universal app**. So it is running on the iPad in emulation mode as an iPhone app in a reduced frame.

Comment: I just remember after posting this question. I checked also in backup of my app there was universal. but someone edit that from today's file so that issue was created